# navigator.mediaDevices is undefined in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, mediadevices, enumerate-devices

Currently i'm creating website that using camera and run in WebView of mobile apps (IOS and Android).

I'm using WKWebView to present it in swift 5. But the return of Navigator.mediaDevices is undefined inside webview.

But it's only happen in iOS 14 (14.3, 14.8). When i try it with iOS 15, it works well.

Is the feature still unable in iOS 14?

**Camera js in WebView**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//...
}

if (!navigator.mediaDevices || !navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices) {
    swal("enumerateDevices is not supported.");
   
}
```

**WKWebView**

```
let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    webConfiguration.requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback = false
    agreeButton.isEnabled = false
    webView.frame = container.bounds
    webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    webView.scrollView.delegate = self
    webView.scrollView.bounces = false
    
    webView = WKWebView(frame: container.frame, configuration: webConfiguration)
    container.addSubview(webView)
    request = URLRequest(url: link)
    webView.load(request)
```